# How to add groovy variable in jenkins groovy email template

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm using a custom variable in my jenkins pipeline and I'm trying to add it to email by modifying groovy-html.template. But I'm getting an error in my email.

```
            steps {
            script {
                MD5SUM=sh(script: 'cat /tmp/DFS_MDSUM.txt', returnStdout: true)
                echo MD5SUM
                def mailRecipients = 'sai****@****.com'
                def jobName = currentBuild.fullDisplayName
                emailext body: '''${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html-test.template"}''',
                mimeType: 'text/html',
                subject: "[Jenkins] ${jobName}",
                to: "${mailRecipients}",
                replyTo: "${mailRecipients}",
                recipientProviders: [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']]
             }
        }
```

Below is the modification I made in groovy-html.template

```
    <tr>
  <td>Duration:</td>
  <td>${build.durationString}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Causeabcdef:</td>
  <td><% build.causes.each() { cause -> %> ${hudson.Util.xmlEscape(cause.shortDescription)} <%  } %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  **<td>MD5SUM:</td>
  <td>MD5SUM of the binary is ${MD5SUM}</td>**
</tr>
```

Befor adding MD5SUM, the email is getting generated without any issue. After adding it, Jenkins job is getting completed as successfull but I'm getting renderring error in email.

[Email without error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMq1x.png)
[Email renderring error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps5Ot.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful trick to expose variables from the pipeline to the email template:

Make MD5SUM an environment variable:

```
steps {
    script {
        env.MD5SUM=sh(script: 'cat /tmp/DFS_MDSUM.txt', returnStdout: true)
        echo env.MD5SUM
        def mailRecipients = 'sai****@****.com'
        def jobName = currentBuild.fullDisplayName
        emailext body: '''${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html-test.template"}''',
        mimeType: 'text/html',
        subject: "[Jenkins] ${jobName}",
        to: "${mailRecipients}",
        replyTo: "${mailRecipients}",
        recipientProviders: [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']]
    }
}
```

In your email template do:

```
<%
//Access job's env vars 
def envOverrides = it.getAction("org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl").getOverriddenEnvironment()
//Now envOverrides is the entrypoint for job's env vars you can do whatever you want
//Init new var
MD5SUM = envOverrides["MD5SUM"]
%>
<tr>
  <td>Duration:</td>
  <td>${build.durationString}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Causeabcdef:</td>
  <td><% build.causes.each() { cause -> %> ${hudson.Util.xmlEscape(cause.shortDescription)} <%  } %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  **<td>MD5SUM:</td>
  <td>MD5SUM of the binary is ${MD5SUM}</td>**
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a Jenkins shared library and what I did is to create a singleton class named JobData that represents all relevant information that I need to collect during the build and I've override class's toString method to represent all fields as json:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

@Singleton
public class JobData{
    //singleton for storing job data

    public String releaseBranch
    public Constants.PipelineType pipelineType
    public def debPackages = [:]
    public def imagesURL = []
    public def commitsIds = []
    
    //[more functions can be implemented here]


    @Override
    String toString() {
        return """{
                    "releaseBranch" : "${this.releaseBranch}", 
                    "pipelineType" : "${this.pipelineType}", 
                    "debPackages" : ${JsonOutput.toJson(this.debPackages)},
                    "imagesURL" : ${JsonOutput.toJson(this.imagesURL)},
                    "commitIds" : ${JsonOutput.toJson(this.commitsIds)}
                }"""
    }
```

Then, in the `post` steps I'm exporting the job data:

```
post{
    always{
        echo " always ".center(61, "=")
        script{
            env.JOB_DATA = JobData.instance.toString() //export JOB_DATA to be available for email templates
        }
    }
}
```

And at the beginning of the email-template script:

```
<%
   import  net.sf.json.JSONSerializer

   def envOverrides = it.getAction("org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl").getOverriddenEnvironment()
   
   jobData = JSONSerializer.toJSON(envOverrides["JOB_DATA"])

   //Now you can access job data
   def a = jobData.releaseBranch
%>
```

...